# JQuery and Javascript to pan image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to implement a panning effect on an image, by following this [tutorial](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-image-panning/). However, it's not working and I think it may be due to the [way](https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/) the javascript is being referenced. The image that I would like to receive the panning effect stays static and does not pan like the [demo.](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/jquery-image-panning/demo/demo.html)

This is what I have tried so far:

I have the following javascript (from the mentioned tutorial, except for a modification in class name) in: `moesia-child-01/scripts/pan.js`

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- JS -->
<script>
  (function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){
      //call imagePanning fn when DOM is ready
      $(".pan img").imagePanning();
    });

    //imagePanning fn
    $.fn.imagePanning=function(){
      var init="center",
        speed=800, //animation/tween speed
        //custom js tween
        _tweenTo=function(el,prop,to,duration,easing,overwrite){
          if(!el._mTween){el._mTween={top:{},left:{}};}
          var startTime=_getTime(),_delay,progress=0,from=el.offsetTop,elStyle=el.style,_request,tobj=el._mTween[prop];
          if(prop==="left"){from=el.offsetLeft;}
          var diff=to-from;
          if(overwrite!=="none"){_cancelTween();}
          _startTween();
          function _step(){
            progress=_getTime()-startTime;
            _tween();
            if(progress>=tobj.time){
              tobj.time=(progress>tobj.time) ? progress+_delay-(progress-tobj.time) : progress+_delay-1;
              if(tobj.time<progress+1){tobj.time=progress+1;}
            }
            if(tobj.time<duration){tobj.id=_request(_step);}
          }
          function _tween(){
            if(duration>0){
              tobj.currVal=_ease(tobj.time,from,diff,duration,easing);
              elStyle[prop]=Math.round(tobj.currVal)+"px";
            }else{
              elStyle[prop]=to+"px";
            }
          }
          function _startTween(){
            _delay=1000/60;
            tobj.time=progress+_delay;
            _request=(!window.requestAnimationFrame) ? function(f){_tween(); return setTimeout(f,0.01);} : window.requestAnimationFrame;
            tobj.id=_request(_step);
          }
          function _cancelTween(){
            if(tobj.id==null){return;}
            if(!window.requestAnimationFrame){clearTimeout(tobj.id);
            }else{window.cancelAnimationFrame(tobj.id);}
            tobj.id=null;
          }
          function _ease(t,b,c,d,type){
            var ts=(t/=d)*t,tc=ts*t;
            return b+c*(0.499999999999997*tc*ts + -2.5*ts*ts + 5.5*tc + -6.5*ts + 4*t);
          }
          function _getTime(){
            if(window.performance && window.performance.now){
              return window.performance.now();
            }else{
              if(window.performance && window.performance.webkitNow){
                return window.performance.webkitNow();
              }else{
                if(Date.now){return Date.now();}else{return new Date().getTime();}
              }
            }
          }
        };
      return this.each(function(){
        var $this=$(this),timer,dest;
        if($this.data("imagePanning")) return;
        $this.data("imagePanning",1)
          //create markup
          .wrap("<div class='img-pan-container' />")
          .after("<div class='resize' style='position:absolute; width:auto; height:auto; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden; z-index:-1'><iframe style='width:100%; height:0; border:0; visibility:visible; margin:0' /><iframe style='width:0; height:100%; border:0; visibility:visible; margin:0' /></div>")
          //image loaded fn
          .one("load",function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ $this.addClass("loaded").trigger("mousemove",1); },1);
          }).each(function(){ //run load fn even if cached
            if(this.complete) $(this).load();
          })
          //panning fn
          .parent().on("mousemove touchmove MSPointerMove pointermove",function(e,p){
            var cont=$(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            var contH=cont.height(),contW=cont.width(),
              isTouch=e.type.indexOf("touch")!==-1,isPointer=e.type.indexOf("pointer")!==-1,
              evt=isPointer ? e.originalEvent : isTouch ? e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0] : e,
              coords=[
                !p ? evt.pageY-cont.offset().top : init==="center" ? contH/2 : 0,
                !p ? evt.pageX-cont.offset().left : init==="center" ? contW/2 : 0
              ];
            dest=[Math.round(($this.outerHeight(true)-contH)*(coords[0]/contH)),Math.round(($this.outerWidth(true)-contW)*(coords[1]/contW))];
          })
          //resize fn
          .find(".resize iframe").each(function(){
            $(this.contentWindow || this).on("resize",function(){
              $this.trigger("mousemove",1);
            });
          });
        //panning animation 60FPS
        if(timer) clearInterval(timer);
        timer=setInterval(function(){
          _tweenTo($this[0],"top",-dest[0],speed);
          _tweenTo($this[0],"left",-dest[1],speed);
        },16.6);
      });
    }

  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

In functions.php, I have added these functions to register the script for a theme and enqueue the script:

```
function my_js_scripts()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'pan-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/pan.js' );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pan-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_js_scripts' );
```

In my theme header.php, I added this line just before wp_head():

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

And this line just after wp_head():

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/pan.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

I have added the jquery parameter to my script registry, but it still does not work.

```
function my_js_scripts()
    {
        // Register the script like this for a theme:
        wp_register_script( 'pan-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/pan.js', ['jquery'] );

        // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
        wp_enqueue_script( 'pan-script' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_js_scripts' );
```

**UPDATE 2**
*I have these Chrome developer console errors*:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/mysite/wp-content/themes/moesia/scripts/pan.js?ver=4.4.2  ?page_id=15:143
GET http://localhost:8888/scripts/pan.js  ?page_id=15:193
```

I figured out from these 404 errors on the pan.js file, that it was looking in the parent theme folder (moesia) instead of the child theme folder (moesia-child-01) for the javascript file.

I would prefer to be able to keep my scripts in the child theme folder--how to do this?

To test this out, however, I have now copied the scripts folder to the parent theme folder (there is now a copy in `moesia/scripts/pan.js`)--Note: not preferable!

I now see that I have a syntax error on pan.js, but cannot see where it is coming from:

```
pan.js?ver=4.4.2:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

**Final Result**

Based on a suggestion from another SO user, I deleted the tags. At first, this resulted in a jquery undefined error when testing the code outside of Wordpress. However, the code now works when using in Wordpress as I had already referenced jquery in this way in header.php:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

Comment: Could you please add more detail. I shouldn't have to read through a tutorial, to see what your issue is.

Comment: @ItsGreg Do you want more detail on the actual js implementation? Or the issue that I am having at hand. See my updated question.

Comment: And as this is really a wordpress question, it should probably have been asked over at the [WordPress StackOverflow website.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @zipzit good suggestion--just joined the site and posted over there: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217893/jquery-and-javascript-to-pan-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add the script tag. The registration will do the trick. However, you need to add a dependency to your registration. Your script depends on JQuery so add it as a dependency:

```
  wp_register_script( 'pan-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/pan.js', ['jquery'] );
```

Comment: I tried adding the jquery parameter and the javascript still doesn't seem to be picking up. See updated question.

Comment: Test your code first outside of wordpress. That way you make sure it works, and you eliminate Wordpress requirements as the issue. Also inspect the html source in the browser and look for your code or script tag.

Comment: I tested the code outside of Wordpress. Indeed, I get a syntax error on the second line of pan.js (Uncaught syntax error: expected token <). However, I don't see why...Is there something wrong with the jquery script line?

Comment: Good so you are getting somewhere. But your plugin is another topic. By the way tags don't belong in JS files. So remove them. Keep ONLY javascript code.

Comment: hm...sorry, which plugin?

Comment: The jquery plugin you built.

Comment: Oh, okay, the jquery from the tutorial that i'm trying to implement? You think it belongs in another question?

Comment: I believe what he means is that you need to remove the script tags from pan.js - .js files should only contain what is between those tags. To make this work I'd say you need to: 1. Remove the first 5 lines from pan.js (from `<!-- jQuery -->` to `<script>`) 2. Remove the last line from pan.js (`</script>`)

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly Does this mean that I should define jquery elsewhere? Doing what you suggested gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: Are you no longer including jQuery as a dependency when you enqueue the script?

Comment: You also should remove the literal script tag you have added after wp_head.